# Что делает этап (жизни)? Может, к примеру, прийти?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

> А ещё: ведь приходит в жизни артиста этап, когда он должен многое
>   пересмотреть, обдумать и даже продумать смену амплуа. Должен учиться
>   соизмерять свои силы, должен понимать, что если не встаёт с кровати
>   утром и готов лежать весь день, то не потому, что он лентяй, а потому,
>   что самые обыденные вещи отнимают гораздо больше сил, чем прежде.

Нет, это не совсем "честная" цитата. В оригинале так (с игрой совершенного/несовершенного вида; скобки - мои, в расчёт не брать):

> А ещё: ведь приходит в жизни артиста этап (МОМЕНТ?), когда он должен
>   многое пересматривать, обдумывать и даже продумать смену амплуа.
>   Должен учиться соизмерять свои силы, должен понимать, что если не
>   встаёт с кровати утром и готов лежать весь день, то не потому, что он
>   лентяй, а потому, что те же (УБРАТЬ!) самые (ОБЫДЕННЫЕ) вещи отнимают
>   гораздо больше сил, чем прежде.

Что делать-то?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А может, вместо "этапа" сказать "время"?

А ещё: ведь приходит в жизни артиста время, когда он должен многое пересмотреть, обдумать и даже **подумать** о  смене амплуа. Должен **привыкнуть к мысли о необходимости**  соизмерять свои силы, должен понимать, что если не встаёт с кровати утром и готов лежать весь день, то не потому, что он лентяй, а потому, что самые обыденные вещи отнимают **теперь** гораздо больше сил, чем прежде.

Answer (score 1):

Точно не момент, тк он краткосрочный а речь о продолжительном времени. Этап подразумевает закономерность и необходимость, в отличии от периода.

Придти этап не может, тк не он идет к чему-то, а к нему идут. Этап может наступить, начаться, близиться.

"обудмать и даже продумать смену амплуа" эта фраза по моему лишина смысла. И кстати по моему весь текст несколько непоследотвальный.

Без "те же" лучше; а если заменить на "даже". А также "отнимают" возможно лучше заменить на "стали отнимать".

Answer (score 1):

**Наступает** этап.
Знаю, это очень поздно. Просто сама гуглила как сказать что делает этап, потом сама додумалась))